# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS No Sound

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound

I have been trying to get my sound to work on my laptop (dual boot with windows), but I am now at my wits end. I have tried many solutions online to no avail. Any suggestions?

System:

- Asus FX503VD
- CPU: Quad Core Intel Core i7-7700HQ (-MT MCP-)
- speed/min/max: 800/800/3800 MHz Kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic x86_64 Up: 7m
- Mem: 1738.3/7844.3 MiB (22.2%) Storage: 1.03 TiB (1.4% used) Procs: 269
- Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38

```
$ sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)


$ sudo lshw -C sound

  *-usb:3                   
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
       vendor: Azurewave
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:7
       version: 3.22
       serial: NULL
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: CM238 HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:135 memory:df420000-df423fff memory:df400000-df40ffff
```

edit: I checked to see if my audio worked on bluetooth and it does (after going through some troubleshooting steps to get bluetooth to work as that wasn't working either). I am also getting weird artifacts on my display and random crash reports. Really considering going back to 18.04, Ubuntu isn't my primary OS and I just need something reliable.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lspci` and `sudo lshw -C sound`? This will contain specific information about the audio system in your notebook which will make it easier to offer specific advice 

Comment: @Matigo I have edited my original post with the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the CM238. Okay ... there are a couple of options for you. Hopefully one of these will be one you haven't tried.

#### Update `alsa-base.conf`

Some Intel audio cards require the `dmic_detect` value to be set to `0`. To do this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit `alsa-base.conf` as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to replace `vi` with your editor of choice.*
2. Add the following line to the end of the file:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
   ```
3. Save and Reboot the machine

If this does not resolve the issue, then ...

#### Reinstall Alsa & PulseAudio

On occasion reinstalling `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` will get things working. To do this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update `apt` and reinstall `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`:

   ```
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
   ```
2. Reload `alsa`:

   ```
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```

If this doesn't work ...

#### Use `pavucontrol`

On occasion I've seen audio "magically" start working after fiddling around in `pavucontrol`. If you don't already have this on your computer, you can install it like so:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Update `apt` and install `pavucontrol`:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install pavucontrol
   ```
2. Run `pavucontrol` by opening the application via application dock. If you would like to use Terminal, you can do so like this:

   ```
   pavucontrol &
   ```
3. Check that the output devices are correct and that the volume sliders are set to 100% (0 db)

If this doesn't work ... I'm not sure. These are the only notes I have for this situation in my notebook

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matigo. Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked.