# Why won't my wired speakers work, when Bluetooth works fine? (pulseaudio bridge to jack)

Tags: sound, kubuntu, speakers, wired

I am running kubuntu 21.04 lowlatency on a Dell Alienware R9 machine, using Studio Controls, which bridges pulseaudio to jack.
I can listen to audio using Bluetooth speakers, but the wired speakers do not show up as audio devices in Audio or pavucontrol.

The problem started with a previous configuration where I had the speaker output hooked up to a component receiver input, and it persists with a new set of Creative Pebble 2.1 speakers. My machine is dual boot and the speakers sound great when I boot into Windows 10, so I don't believe it is a problem with the speakers.

I tried this [Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS No Sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319187/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-no-sound) and found that it introduced a "PCH,1,0-out" icon on my qjackctl "graph" -- which I patched my pulse_out into. but still no sound (except through Bluetooth)

```
    $ inxi
CPU: 8-Core Intel Core i7-9700 (-MCP-) speed/min/max: 800/800/4700 MHz 
Kernel: 5.11.0-25-lowlatency x86_64 Up: 1h 19m Mem: 5615.1/31932.8 MiB (17.6%) 
Storage: 5.24 TiB (1.8% used) Procs: 415 Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.01
```

```
$inxi -A

    Audio: 
Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
Device-3: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-25-lowlatency
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th/9th Gen Core 8-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x8) (rev 0d)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f0)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Serial IO UART Controller #0
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5410 (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C sound
[sudo] password for magraith: 
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: TU116 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:ec080000-ec083fff
  *-usb:3
       description: Video
       product: Webcam C270
       vendor: Logitech, Inc.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       version: 0.12
       serial: 81D52620
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 200 Series PCH HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:154 memory:2fff020000-2fff023fff memory:2fff000000-2fff00ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things jump out, first, this isn't about your speakers, which according to their product description, are standard 1/8" audio jack driven, and USB powered, not usb audio.

So the actual question is why isn't your audio software directing output to the specified audio port.

If you use pulse audio control, that has a convenient way to check the output device actually assigned. Note that you have to generally disable other devices to get pulseaudio to consistently direct the output to where you want it to go, at least I always do. You also have to select the right profile for that hardware device, in this case, it's probably 'analog stereo output'.

So the audio out port you are using has to be from either your nvidia or intel audio device, and pulseaudio has to be told to use that one, it rarely in my experience actually picks the one you want without any manual intervention.

Again, you may be confusing yourself by mixing up where that output is going and the speakers, the speakers you can largely ignore in this, since they are just passive recipients of an audio port signal, and the problem here is probably where that signal is actually going internally for pulseaudio.

The Jack integration may or may not interfere with this, but my guess is if you check the pulse audio volume control thing, make sure the configuration tab shows all audio devices disabled that you aren't using, that is, all off except the one you are using, then the 'output devices' tab port is set to the correct output port, which for a 1/8th inch audio output is going to probably be headphones, it depends.

Again, Jack audio may alter some of these factors, but this would be the first thing I'd check. Almost always when I do not get audio from an output port, aka, plug, it's because these two things were not configured/set correctly, and almost always, pulseaudio fails to automatically detect in particular headphone port changes, maybe also pre out, line out ports. Which port to use depends of course on if you are sending the speakers a line signal, which you would have been sending to your receiver, or a headphone signal, which means your local software volume is controlling the levels, not the volume control on the speakers, if they have any. It sounds like your speakers get a line level signal, and you use the speaker volume controls to adjust the levels.

Bluetooth may also still be grabbing the signal, bluetooth audio is not awesome in linux, and it may just not be releasing the audio, I don't know how that looks because I don't use bluetooth audio in linux since bluetooth is inherently lower fidelity than wired audio.

Comment: thanks for your thoughtful reply.

Comment: in pavucontrol, I see  2 devices: 
TU116 high def audio controller digital stereo hdmi 2
built in audio analog surround 2

I'm not sure what to make of these.
 
in the pavu playback tab, the program that is creating the audio (firefox) shows, and the bar that shows the volume changes says "silence"

my understanding was that the pulse was being directed to jack, and jack had to send the output to the right place. do I have that wrong?

Comment: jack complicates things, I have not yet figured out how to use jack for audio. Try simplifying, remove jack, get it working with pulseaudio, or pipewire, just one of them, then try more complicated things. Don't be afraid of trying different settings, you'll get silence often until you find the right combination, and once you see the input sound bar moving it's pretty easy to figure out which last input to use. Don't know what happens when pulse is running through into jack, that seems almost asking for problems to me. Make sure to REMOVE configuration file changes you make though!!!

Comment: Be clear, your speakers should NOT appear as an audio device, they aren't, they are just what is receiving an analog audio output, so you want to remove that part of the question since its' a red herring and will just confuse people, including yourself. An audio device is a sound card/chip, not a wired speaker plugged in. What you are directing output to is the port the jack plugs into, NOT the device attached to the jack/plug, those will just show as various types of output ports, like headphone, lineout, digital outs, inputs, etc.

Comment: The thing is -- Studio Controls just sets it up like this automatically (pulse bridge to Jack)... and it USED to work for me. It just stopped one day. I figured out that Bluetooth worked so for a while I just did that. But now I want my speakers back. So I could try to shut off jack, but I'll be dismantling the configuration that is in place. But I'll probably learn something in the process. well, I hope so!

Comment: Ah, I see. If you rely on studio controls, and jack, you probably want to learn how those work. I'd check and see if bluetooth has grabbed control, but that's another pain to figure out. I've never been a fan of prepackaged pre configured things, for exactly this reason, you don't learn how it works, so can't readily correct issues if or when they appear. If it 'just stopped one day' that suggests a system update overwrote a configuration. Which would mean the packaging was incorrect, possibly. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/ubuntustudio-controls.1.html that is pretty clear.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to do - learn how it works. Specifically, I'm trying to understand, if I have these output devices, how do I make sure they are mapped to the right port so the sound gets to the speaker? Based on what I get out of Bluetooth, it seems like the pulse-jack-bridging  works, it's just that physical devices are not getting the signal (that's a theory). So what lets me diagnose that situation?

Comment: I would not assume that, bluetooth is in almost all cases going through the USB bus, and is significantly different. Also, once you go with the latency of bluetooth and usb, all benefits from using jack vanish instantly. It would not surprise me if jack was not involved in  that chain at all, since there is basically zero benefit to using it in that context. The purpose of Jack is to drop latency to the minimum required to do real audio work, not listening, mind you, processing/recording, etc, audio work. Bluetooth would NEVER be used in that context.

Comment: well the one piece of evidence that supports my theory is that, with Bluetooth as my output, the USB webcam microphone did not work until I patched it into the pulse in, using QJackCtl's "graph"

Comment: that said, I have shut off Jack, Pulseaudio has taken over, and oi-la, I have audio again. So thanks for encouraging me to break it down.

Comment: for issues like this, simplifying it first then adding complexity makes it easier to follow and fix the stuff, that's generally how I approach matters. Making very complex first then trying to figure out which variable makes it not work rarely turns out well, lol, in programming. So it was jack. My suspicion is that either bluetooth or an ubuntu update overwrote or altered a key configuration the initial ubuntu package studio controls created.